# Что возвращает функция

Tags: php

```
function check_login($login, $pass) {
    return ($_POST['login'] == 'root') && ($_POST['pass'] == '123321');
}
```

Правильно я понимаю, что данная функция возвращает true/false в зависимости от совпадения логин/пароль? Не понимаю что за сокращенный синтаксис if'ов..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подумайте сами. Сравнение ведь само по себе возвращает true или false, правильно?

Поехали дальше. Первая часть есть true тогда и только тогда, когда login был root, правильно? А вторая -- если pass был 123321. То есть всё вместе будет true если login root, и pass 123321. И разумеется false в обратном случае.

Вы видите, что никакие `if`'ы не нужны.

То есть в принципе функцию можно было бы переписать с `if`'ами, более привычным образом, вот так:

```
function check_login($login, $pass) {
    $result = ($_POST['login'] == 'root') && ($_POST['pass'] == '123321');
    if ($result == true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Или так:

```
function check_login($login, $pass) {
    $result = ($_POST['login'] == 'root') && ($_POST['pass'] == '123321');
    if ($result == true) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Но зачем?

Comment: VladD, спасибо за разъяснение. Когда будет true, а когда false, мне было понятно. Меня смутил именно синтаксис, разве так приемлемо? Видела сокращенный вариант условного оператора, но он немножко не такой был, насколько я помню

Comment: @sof_ka: Хороший вопрос. Конечно, приемлемо! Булево выражение можно не только "скармливать" в `if`, оно в принципе ничем не отличается от например числа. Вы же не видите проблем в коде `return 3 + 5;`? Булево выражение ничем не хуже.

Comment: @sof_ka: наоборот, для меня код

    if (expr) { return true; } else { return false; }

или

    return expr ? true : false;

кажется избыточным: ведь мы в любом случае возвращаем ровно то, что есть значение нашего `expr`, зачем же его лишний раз проверять?

Comment: Да, вы правы :) Спасибо

Comment: @sof_ka: Пожалуйста!